# Meaning and origin - "More on point than a sock"

Tags: expressions

In TV Show "Elementary" - Season 2 - Chapter 15, Dr Watson starts saying:

> More on point than a sock

What is the meaning of this expression? What is the relationships with "points" and "socks"?

Context:

[**Corpse de Ballet**](http://www.geekinsider.com/elementary-recap-s02e15-corpse-de-ballet/)

> It’s an average morning at the brownstone, which means Sherlock has an entirely consensual, entirely independent ladyfriend over and has politely informed Joan of this fact via post-it, which Joan considers more “on point” than a sock on the handle. (It’s a [ballet pun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/en+pointe), like the title. The writers are having fun this episode.) After politely offering their guest coffee, Joan and Sherlock are called to a murder investigation– Nell Solange, a ballet dancer, was cut in two by a wire in the theater rafters.

[image]

Comment: Is it [this](http://41.media.tumblr.com/0205d79c5286856c0d58ac787f50787a/tumblr_n1k1ht4IM81r89uf5o1_1280.jpg) moment?

Comment: Yes and it is even a [pun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/en+pointe) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If @Kreiri is correct, than "sock" refers to hanging a sock on the outside door knob of your dorm room to warn your roommate not to enter because you are inside having sex.  Go [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=doorsock).  The explicit sign on the door is more to the point than the symbolic sock.

Comment: Thanks! I failed to notice the context, and for some reason I thought it was some sort of folk-ish expression. It makes perfect sense.